# How to connect to Blue tooth printer from windows Phone 8 in native c++

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to get PeerInfo structure get filled with mac address of my BT printer and then use it with Sockstream coonectAsync API.Any c++ code please help....I have done this in C# but not in C++

Comment: Are you looking for C++.Net (XAML) or straight C++ for a library?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br225433.aspx) to locate the associated bluetooth device.
2. Use [RFcommDeviceService::FromIdAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.rfcommdeviceservice.fromidasync.aspx) to turn the device id in to a service.
3. Use StreamSocket::ConnectAsync() to connect to the `RfCommDeviceService::ConnectionHostName`

From there you should be good.